# In a MIPS program, how can you print the contents of the instruction memory in hex?

Tags: mips, spim, disassembly, qtspim

I was wondering if there was an easy method/code to display the contents of the instruction memory in hex format onto the the console in a MIPS program?

Comment: Using what tool?  A debugger like `gdb` can do this quite easily.